# How to convert from $this->text to $this->data in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to compare the title of a page to a certain value in a skin for MediaWiki. The page  title can be outputted using:

```
<?php $this->text('title') ?>
```

This works and will output the page title (in this case "Main Page"), however it will not allow me to compare the value to anything, for example:

```
<?php if ($this->text('title') == "Main Page") { echo "You are on the Main Page!"; } ?>
```

This will output "Main Page", not "You are on the Main Page!"

The fix for this would be to use $this->data instead of $this->text, but $this->data('title') is not defined in MediaWiki. How can I convert the output of $this->text to a variable that can be compared without echoing anything to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->text('title') does not return the title of the page. Instead, it echoes the title into the skin template. You can verify this by looking at the code for the text() function.

What you need is $this->data['title'].

$this->data is an array so $this->data('title') is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's output buffering features to capture it, e.g.:

```
ob_start();
$this->text('title');
$title = ob_get_clean();

if($title == 'Main Page') {...}
```

Although there's almost definitely a way to get it directly. I don't have any experience with MediaWiki, but there looks to be a few useful methods in the [`OutputPage`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aOutputPage.php) class, e.g. `getPageTitle()`. There's also a [`Title`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTitle.php) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to get the output of `$this->text('title')`

For example:

```
ob_start();
$this->text('title');
$title = ob_get_clean();
```